# Dilemma backbone, javascript return

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i've this function that login in parse.com but i' don't understand why if i delete return false statement it don't work and go in error.

```
log_in:function(){
    console.log("login");
    var username = this.$("#login-username").val();
    var password = this.$("#login-password").val();

    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);

    Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
        success: function(user) {
            console.log("login riuscito");
            window.location='index.html'  ;
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            console.log(error + user + "login <<<<<<non riuscito");
        }
    });
    return false; <<<---------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know how the log_in function is called by your code.

Comment: and what the `logIn` function is doing. I assume it's asynchronous.